# Does android replay last events after rotating the device

Tags: android

I using `android.app.Fragment` with a `LinearLayout` that contains one `android.widget.EditText` inside it and i dont have landspace layout folder. A `android.text.TextWatcher` is added to the EditText via `addTextChangedListener`.  Say i enter a letter "a" into the EditText and i rotate the android device. I would expect the existing Fragment to be completly destroyed and a new instance of Fragment to be created. Also, i expect the EditText to be empty in the new Fragement. But to my surprise, following happens:-

1. Both Fragment and its containing Activity are completely destroyed
2. A new instance of Fragment and Activity are created. So far good. this is per my expectation.
3. BUT, the last events on EditText are replayed. The last events were beforeTextChanged() and onTextChanged(). How is this possible? If a new instance of fragment is created, this would imply a new instance of EditText is created, then who is reposible for replaying the last events on EditText?

Comment: What do you mean that "the last events on EditText are replayed"? Check the arguments to `beforeTextChanged()` and `onTextChanged()`. I suspect that the values are different before and after the orientation change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the following sequence of events during a configuration change describe:

1. **The Activity and all its Fragments are given a chance to store their current state in `onSaveInstanceState().**
2. The Activity and all its Fragments are destroyed
3. The Activity and all its Fragments are created again.
4. **The state of the Activity and Fragments are restored.** If you have not explicitly overridden `onSaveInstanceState()` and you call `super.onCreate()` from your own `onCreate()` methods, this means that Android will restore the state of any widgets such as `EditText`s. For each `EditText`, restoring the text causes a call to `beforeTextChanged()` and `onTextChanged()`.

Note that step 3 isn't the same as "replaying the previous events" because the values of the parameters to `beforeTextChanged()` and `onTextChanged()` will indicate a change of more than just one character.